# C# efficiently redraw Image with new data

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management, bitmap

What is the most memory efficient way to redraw an Image with new data in C#?

The external DLL I am using allocates a byte buffer to hold my (width * hight * bytesPerPixel) pixel data where each pixel is in ARGB32 format. The DLL automatically updates that buffer with new data by interacting with hardware, and then calls a C# callback saying that new data is ready to go. Right now, my scheme for displaying the new data is

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(_size.Width, _size.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var bitmapData = bmp.LockBits(
                new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), _size), 
                ImageLockMode.UserInputBuffer | ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, 
                unmanagedByteDataPtr);
bmp.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
myGui.ImageCtrl.Image = bmp;
```

This creates a new bitmap every time, which has a memory/performance penalty. Since my image size is not changing, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong constructor. Just create a bitmap directly from the unmanaged data, and it will *wrap* the data, rather than creating a new bitmap just to throw it away immediately:

```
new Bitmap(_size.Width, _size.Height, 4 * _size.Width, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb,
           unmanagedByteDataPtr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this out, but it doesn't seem to improve CPU not memory utilization. Isn't this suggestion still creating a new bitmap object every time? As I understand it, both methods simply reference the actual unmanaged pixel data as buffers. So, this leads me to believe that the memory/CPU usage comes from the fact that I am creating and disposing bitmap objects on every frame.

Comment: @PaulGrinberg Have you used a profiler? The `Bitmap` object itself has no data, it's just a wrapper for a GDI+ bitmap, which again only references your memory location, rather than copying it. Maybe your problem is simply somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After realizing that my problem is not the bitmap creation, I went looking for the memory leak elsewhere and found it.